# Schema.org in real estate online site

Tags: seo, schema.org

I am new to SEO. I recently came across Schema.org which is a shared vocabulary that can be used to markup a web site.

I am working in an online portal where user can buy/sell homes, like `99acres.com`, `magicbricks.com` or `housing.com`.

Though I read about Schema.org, I can't find any relevant concrete vocab like a vocab that can allow me to markup web pages like "no. of bhk" or "flat/bedroom size" etc., though there are some common vocab like `Residence`,`GeoCoordinates` I can use.

I would like to know that at this point, considering there is no complete vocab for real estate, is it worthwhile to use Schema.org for online real estate website?

Answer (score 1):

For everything, that you can't find appropriate type in the Schema.org's dictionary, you can use a fallback to `sameAs` and `additionalType`. So the example of your code would be like the following: you use an `Offer` as the main type, then you add the `potentialAction` type (`rent` or `sell`).

Every detail of your offer you describe as the block built from `includesObject`→`TypeAndQuantityNode`→`name`, `sameAs` (to describe it with the dbpedia URI) and `amountOfThisGood`

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://dbpedia.org/page/Condominium" />
<link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/SingleFamilyResidence" />

<link itemprop="potentialAction" href="https://schema.org/RentAction" />

<span itemprop="name">Best Condominium in Town</span>

<div itemprop="includesObject" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TypeAndQuantityNode">
<span itemprop="name">Bedroom</span>
<link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://dbpedia.org/page/Bedroom" />
<span itemprop="amountOfThisGood">4</span>

</div>

<div itemprop="includesObject" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TypeAndQuantityNode">
<span itemprop="name">Bathroom</span>
<link itemprop="sameAs" href="http://dbpedia.org/page/Bathroom" />
<span itemprop="amountOfThisGood">2</span>

</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...for my site, do I need to use dbpedia urls you have mentioned like http://dbpedia.org/page/Bedroom ??

Comment: Using of sameAs propety linked to DBpedia (or any other structured database) URI is the common way to structurally markup things, which haven't own types in Schema.org's vocabulary. I would say yes, you need it, if you want exactly and on machine readable way describe things you do business with.

Comment: Can i use http://www.productontology.org/id/Bedroom as additionType?

Comment: yes. you can use any of structured databases